Blockchain recovery fee
I've ben trying to recover about 70 000 EUR worth of BTC for years, but every time I was asked to pay a Blockchain recovery fee. I paid few times but the money simply disappeared and I can't get a refund. I'm now in touch with a company that claims to have recovered over 40 000 EUR ( no upfront payment ) but again the transaction is withheld until I pay 200 USD Blockchain Recovery Fee. The amount is not enormous but I'm fed up getting scammed all the time. Can anyone please confirm that such a fee really exists and that I have a chance of seeing my withdrawal transaction comme through ?
